# vsftpd virtual user read permissions

Tags: permissions, vsftpd

I have a `vsftp` server that services a read-only public space by anonymous login. It works fine. I need to add a few specific users that will authenticate by username/password and they will have different user-specific home directories that are also read-only.

I have configured virtual guest users and they can log in (authenticating via PAM). The problem that I have is that these users can only access world-readable files. I don't want to make the files world-readable – they are all owned and accessible by the `nobody` user and they have no group or world permissions.

I have configured `vsftp` so that it runs as `nobody` and so that the guest user name is `nobody` – I would have expected that this meant all guests were 'nobody' and should therefore be able to read files accessible to `nobody`.

The configuration that I added for virtual users is below

```
 # Specific users
 local_enable=YES
 guest_enable=YES
 guest_username=nobody
 user_sub_token=$USER
 local_root=/srv/backup/$USER
 pam_service_name=vsftpd
 allow_writeable_chroot=YES
```

An example home directory (listed from the filesystem):

```
drwx------ 2 nobody nobody 4096 May 15 12:09 a_directory
drwx------ 5 nobody nobody 4096 May  7 12:07 another_directory
-rw------- 1 nobody nobody  95744 May  4 17:07 FILE.txt
-rw------- 1 nobody nobody 104502 Apr 22 17:14 another_file
```

How do I configure `vsftp` so that virtual users can see the files in their directories ?

Comment: Who owns the user's directory? That is, while `cd`'d into the directory containing `a_directory`, what do you get from `ls -ld .`?

Comment: This is the directory /srv/backup/myuser: `drwx------ 7 nobody nobody 4096 May 15 12:02`

Comment: In that case, I suspect you will find your answer in `vsftpd`'s log file.

Comment: 'fraid not. I have already exhausted that source of information I have both `xferlog_enable=YES` and `log_ftp_protocol=YES` but it does provide any further enlightenment. I found to list the contents of a directory it needs 504 permissions and to download a file it needs 404 permissions.

Comment: I've given up and am using `proftpd` instead :)